# Why are volume controls only displayed sometimes with the audio tag?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web

Does anyone know why volume controls aren't being displayed on [this](http://reusable-box.me/) page, but are displayed on [this](http://reusable-box.me:8000/mpd) page?

I know the audio element is interpreted by the browser, but chrome used to show volume controls for the player on the first linked page. I really would like volume control here, and am wondering if there is any way to make sure that control displays alongside the rest of the controls with the controls attribute.

Comment: Just make sure that you have added controls with your audio tag.
    `<audio controls="controls">`

Comment: controls are properly enabled. I just don't get the same controls between both pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The second link treats the element as a video. This shows the volume controls.

Weird.

Fixed now, though.